# Prevent non-ASCII characters from being captured in a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a legacy database column which only supports the ASCII character set. I need a method which prevents non-ASCII characters from being typed or pasted into a UITextView. I need to filter out emojis and all other unicode characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts to this. Firstly, prevent non-ASCII characters from being typed in the first place by setting the keyboard type appropriately:

```
textView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
```

Secondly, prevent non-ASCII characters being pasted in from another app by implementing this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    // trim any non-ASCII characters
    NSString* s = [[text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 128)].invertedSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    // manually replace the range in the textView
    textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:s];

    // prevent auto-replacement
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4** clean code solution

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.canBeConverted(to: .ascii)
}
```

Comment: This fails. With this method, I'm able to get an empty accent characters into the UITextField like these: ´ ¨ `

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using for UITextField, just alternative solution, this works on default as well as custom keyboards and disables copy pasting of emojis. No need to set keyboard type to ascii as it only disables emojis of default iOS keyboard.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    //This is universal solution works on default as well as custom keyboards like SwiftKeyplus it will diallow pasting emoji
    if !string.canBeConvertedToEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: This fails. With this method, I'm able to get an empty accent characters into the UITextField like these: ´ ¨ `